# Fail to update datum in sql server - arithabort error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, arithabort

in an vb.net project, I hardly managed to fix every insert / update queries cause of the arithabort problems I encountered and now, my project works well for me, yesterday, by deploying the application on another server (windows 2003 R2 SP2), I encountered again the arithabort problems and I have no clue of how to fix that again.
To execute an insert / update query, I use an ADODB.Connection object, and just before to run one of them, I execute these 2 following queries:

```
set NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT off
set ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Edit: just noticed on the server, SQL server 2008 is installed, in my case, I use SQL Server 2008 R2, which would explain the error encountered.

Comment: How about adjusting the queries so that ARITHABORT is not raised? E.g. do not divide by zero.

Comment: there was no division in my queries. Modifying manually the ARITHABORT parameter solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I changed manually the value of this parameter : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikkole/archive/2014/01/03/queries-failing-because-of-the-arithabort-setting.aspx
By default, it was set to OFF, now, it's set to ON.